# How do I stop my function keys from acting as media controls?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, media-buttons

Last week my function keys suddenly became media keys. <kbd>F4</kbd> now toggles play status, <kbd>F5</kbd> skips to the next song, and <kbd>F12</kbd> ejects my media tray. When I try to remap them with Keyboard Shortcuts, I'm told that they map to `XF86AudioPlay`, `XF86AudioNext`, and `XF86AudioEject`.

How do I get the old function key mapping back? If possible I'd like to avoid creating a keyboard mapping file - I didn't have one before these problems, so I'd just like to return to that state.